# Change/override text color in a Ninja Form using Tempera Theme

Tags: css, forms

I am currently using the Cryout Creations Tempera Theme. I am having difficulty changing the font from white to black in the forms I have created through Ninja Forms.

Comment: http://devieworks.ieworks.net/

Comment: On which page? Can you be more specific?

Comment: You'll need to add more detail here. The link you provided doesn't seem to have any forms, while the Contact page form already has black text. Try using your browser's 'Inspect Element' tool to narrow down the problem and consider rewording your question to be more specific.